# Получить длину маршрута не показывая на странице сами яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему
В простейшем виде получить длину оптимального маршрута между двумя точками с заданными координатами.
Например через multirouter driving - Построение автомобильного мультимаршрута.
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving

На странице  - https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/59353 я нашел пост

*Маршрут нельзя не показывать согласно ПС*

Но в новой актуальной версии пользовательского соглашения я прямых запретов не нашел. Могу ли я использовать это апи без отображения карт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условия пользования API Яндекс.Карт оговорены здесь: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/

Про запрет использования данных без отображения на карте говорится в третьем пункте этих правил.

> ***Результаты всех запросов к** API **должны быть отображены на карте Яндекса**. Например, это данные, полученные с помощью сервиса
> геокодирования или **маршрутизации**.*

Этот момент обходится покупкой платного ключа. И если есть какие-то разночтения или непонятные моменты в правилах Яндекса, лучше обращаться сразу в их поддержку, а не сюда.